# Accessing the elements looped over with .each() without calling $(this)

Tags: jquery

I am using `.each()` to iterate over the links in the jQuery object `$firstParagraph`. As I iterate over the links, I would like to refer to them in an **absolute** way, without calling `$(this)` which creates a new object each time it is called. Because when I iterate twice independently over the links (as shown in the code below), then the work done in both instances is not combined.

```
$firstParagraph = $("p").eq(0);

// Iterate over the links once
$firstParagraph.find("a").each( function()
    {
        $this = $(this);
        // Modify $this
    });

// Iterate over the links a second time
$firstParagraph.find("a").each( function()
    {
        $this = $(this);
        // I want to modify $this again, but without loosing
        // the work I did in the first iteration
    });
```

Comment: You shouldn't be modifying `$(this)`.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Why dont you combine both the logic in just one loop?

Comment: the poster is not trying to mod the this object >.>

Comment: For anyone to meaningfully answer this question, you really need to tell us what you're doing in the two loops. You may well not need to create jQuery instances at all, if all you're doing is stuff that's easily done without using the jQuery wrapper you're trying to avoid creating (like getting/setting the anchor's `id`, `href`, etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of going violently against the grain of jQuery like you're asking, let me advise you how to do what you actually need to do: use `$(this).data('somekey', someval)` and `$(this).data('somekey')` to, instead of directly modifying `$(this)` as an object and so losing whatever you're trying to do, attach data to your concept of `$(this)` in such a way that you'll be able to get it back.  (Docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/data).)

Comment: This sounds very promising. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you append to Array? As you are using simple variables it will always overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var elemArray = [];
// Iterate over the links once
$firstParagraph.find("a").each( function(i)
    {
        $this = $(this);
        elemArray[i] = $this;
        // Modify $this
    });

// Iterate over the links a second time
$firstParagraph.find("a").each( function(i)
    {
        $this = elemArray[i];
        // I want to modify $this again, but without loosing
        // the work I did in the first iteration
    });
```

I'm not sure if this is a good idea as things can change between the two loops.